# Why does inline-block not render the elements inline in this code example?

Tags: html, css

The following code seems to render the input field on the line below its label in all browsers:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    label { display:inline-block; width:75px }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label>First Name <input type="text" name="first_name" size="30" maxlength="30"/></label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how it appears:

First Name
[input field]

My understanding is that inline-block should allow for a fixed width for the label, whilst still permitting the input element to be inline.  This is how I expected it to appear:

First Name [input field]

Why does the addition of a fixed width for the label in this instance not allow for both elements to appear inline?

Comment: Why don't you try using class and ID's for adding CSS properties ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Albeit your version is semantically correct, you have to do it like this to get your desired behavior:

HTML

```
<form>
  <label for="first_name">First Name</label><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" size="30" maxlength="30"/>
</form>
```

CSS

```
label {
  display:inline-block;
  width:75px;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2Wnj/)

That way, the `label` and the `input` are separated from each other and can flow free. If the `label` holds the `input`, that is not the case; even when setting the `label` to `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Probably should give it a `for` attribute for proper click behavior.

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. Also, setting cursor to pointer is a good idea. I will edit my answer, thanks.

Comment: Also note that the `for="first_name"` targets the input with the **id** `first_name` (rather than the name attribute).

Answer (score 2):

Your label wraps the input. 75px probably isn't enough width for both the text and input without word wrapping

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me : Just make it display:inline

```
 <style type="text/css">
    label { display:inline; width:75px }
    </style>
```

Comment: The reason this "works" is because `width` doesn't do anything to an inline element.